# Rewriting with Apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have this setup ..

- /plain index file
- /sub_dir1
- /sub_dir2 (<-subdomain)
- /sub_dir3
- /blog (<-wordpress)
- /etc/

but want this ..

- /wordpress
- /sub_dir1
- /sub_dir2 (<-subdomain)
- /sub_dir3
- /etc/

Is this possible with wordpress' rewrite rules etc?
Any advice on the Apache rules?

Cheers,
Jeremy

Comment: What do you want the wordpress url to be?

mysite.com/wordpress or wordpress.mysite.com or just mysite.com ?

Comment: Hi Keyo - good point, I wasn't clear. 
mysite.com - but I'd prefer to keep the data in /blog if I can. So / rewrites to /blog with a url of mysite.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Should rewrite everything which isn't a file into the blog folder.

Comment: Keyo thank you!! The only other thing I added was a rule for the index file in root.
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /blog/index.php
Cheers!